# Swift ViewController without prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift

On my project I have a Master controller (Which is accessed by a segue that has three nibs. **These nibs are not on the main storyboard** They only show on the master view and I can swipe across to view them.

How do I get from any one of those nibs to the ViewController that sent them?

For Clarity

- ViewController1

  - segue to ViewController2

    - display slide nibs (ViewController3).

I want to get from ViewController3 to ViewController1 but they are not on the storyboard so I cant click and drag and make a segue.

I hope this makes sense.

Edit: IBAction

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1StoryBoardID") as! ViewController1
presentViewController(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

ViewController2 has this:

```
let vc3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController3", bundle: nil) 
var frame3 = self.vc3.view.frame
frame3.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
self.vc3.view.frame = frame3
self.addChildViewController(self.vc3)
self.scrollView.addSubview(self.vc3.view)
self.vc3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

With a few extra lines to add other frames and slide to them

Answer (score 0):

You can instanciate the Viewcontroller through the Storyboard,

```
//instanciate storyboard    
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"StoryboardName", bundle:nil)

let myViewcontroller = mainStoryBoard.instanciateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewcontrolleridentifier") as? ViewController1
```

You can set the identifier in Interface builder

Answer (score 0):

```
let viewController = YourViewController(nibName: "YourViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept in iOS of [Navigation View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html) that will help you to do it in a "professional way". You will "stack" the views, and can get back to any of them, white out a segue, just popping it.

Other way to do it, is moving by the identifier of the view, whithout an explicit segue in storyboard, check [This link](https://coderwall.com/p/hvr8qq/instantiate-a-view-controller-using-a-storyboard-identifier-in-xcode-ios)  for more details

Answer (score 0):

You do it like:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("anIdentifier") as! UIViewController
presentViewController(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

- "StoryboardName" is the name of your storyboard
- "anIdentifier" is the identifier of your UIViewController set in storyboard

Please check the image where to set the storyboard ID of the ViewController:

[image]

Comment: This, throws this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[test.ViewReportViewController returnToOriginal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ba2f740'

Comment: Can you post your piece of code here how you do the transition ?

Comment: Yeah, gimme a few mins.

Comment: in the appdelegate.swift class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate {

Comment: Well, it's hard to say. The example I posted is a standard way how to transit to a view controller without segue, but it looks like there is something other wrong in your code. Are you reaching this function presentViewController(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil) ? Is it executed at all ?